# How to run regression analysis without extracted factors from factor anlaysis?

Tags: regression, categorical-data

I used Oblique Rotation in my Factor Analysis to reduce the dimensions and to extract 4 factors. But Since I was using Oblique rotation, the results of Factor Analysis did not contain the extracted factors' dataset that I can use in the following regression analysis.

How can I run the regression analysis without using the extracted factors' data? Should I calculate Z Score of each factor or question items to run regression analysis? CONFUSED.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused what you're confused about. If I understood your question correctly, your plan is to perform regression analysis, using factors, extracted during exploratory factor analysis (EFA). Let's assume that your original data set contains $N$ observations and $k$ columns, equal to the total number of factors. Your EFA resulted in 4 extracted factors (not the corresponding data, as you rightly noted), let's call them $f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4$. So, the next step, I think, would be to perform regression analysis on a **subset of the original data set**, containing only columns, corresponding to the extracted factors. Therefore, both goals will be achieved: performing EFA and regression.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question. Your understanding is correct. My following question is how I can use the re-patterned raw data to run regression analysis?  Each extracted factor has been measured by 6-7 items/variables. How can I combined the 6-7 variables' raw data into ONE data set to represent ONE factor?

Comment: Sorry...if the question is my pretty dummy level. :-)

Comment: @AvaXU: No need to apologize - we are all here to learn :-). In regard to your subsequent question, I'm not sure that it's a good idea to answer it in comments. I will offer you a direction, but, if you need more detailed answer, I suggest you to either update your question by incorporating the second one, or by submitting a separate question. (to be continued)

Comment: @AvaXU: (cont'd) The direction: your second question implies that you're talking about _latent variables_, measured by a number of items (indicators) and, thus, [latent variable model (LVM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_variable_model). Depending on the nature of your latent variables and indicators, a particular type of LVM should be used; see [this presentation](http://www.econ.upf.edu/~michael/latentvariables/lecture1.pdf), pages 5-7. It is a large topic, so that is all I will say now.

Comment: Thanks for your direction. How can I give you a BIG HUG!? ;-)  I need some time to digest the new concept.

Comment: @AvaXU: You're very welcome! Don't worry about a big hug, though I don't mind ;-). You definitely need time to digest the material, even to scratch the surface - it's a large and rather complex area, usually referred to as umbrella terms _latent variable modeling_ and [_structural equation modeling_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_equation_modeling). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

2 major approaches on how to use Factor analysis with regression.

**Approach1** conduct factor analysis and save scores for extracted factors. use these extracted factors as independent variable in your regression model. [I have answered this already here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146643/regression-analysis-or-structural-equation-modelling/146653#146653)

**Approach2** conduct factor analysis to understand factor structure. Use summated scales to construct independent variable separately. [quick tutorial on how to do this in SPSS](http://essedunet.nsd.uib.no/cms/topics/regression/8/1.html)