# Regression analysis or Structural Equation Modelling

Tags: multiple-regression, dataset, structural-equation-modeling

I have a 26 items questionnaire refined by running Common Factor Analysis. As a result, I got 4 factors (f1, f2, f3, f4). Each factor is measured by 6-7 items in the questionnaire. These four extracted factors would be my Independent Variables. I also have two Dependent Variables. What I want to know is the relationship between the 4 IVs and the 2 DVs.

If I use regression analysis, how can I calculate the extracted factor datasets based on the raw data of 6-7 items?

If I use SEM, how can I change 26 items dataset to 4 factors dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have 3 questions.
1) **how to calculate the extracted factor datasets based on the raw data of 6-7 items**:
you can save factor scores, also known as 'Regression score' in SPSS and R
Check this quick [SPSS tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X0RdXyGbJDY)

2) **If you use SEM, how to change 26 items dataset to 4 factors dataset**: SEM requires a theoritical support before you can build model. Lets say you come to know that from a previous study. You can however build models based on factor structure found in factor analysis. Check this [detailed SEM tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZWIbT7PbDA&list=PLnMJlbz3sefLdYnz7TysHKrMBby7igpV9)

3) **Whether to use SEM or regression analysis**: Depends on what you want to measure. If you want to measure effects of factors and underlying 6-7 items on both the dependent variable simultaneously, SEM will be ideal. Regression can however measure only one dependent variable at at time. So one model for dependent 1 with 4 factors, another separate model for dependent 2 with 4 factors.

All the best!

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I think I would go with SEM as you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, especially considering that your model is not that simple, I suggest you to switch for this study from using term *regression analysis* to using term *latent variable modeling (LVM)* or, more commonly, *structural equation modeling (SEM)*. The main reason is not the terminology, but emphasizing the fact that SEM encompasses a **comprehensive analysis** of both *measurement model* and *structural model*. In SEM terminology, to analyze a measurement model, you need to perform confirmatory factor analysis (CFA), after you've done EFA, while to analyze a structural model, you need to perform *path analysis*, also referred to as *path modeling (PM)* or simply SEM.

In terms of the SEM process, as I said earlier, it is quite a challenge to grasp all concepts and, especially, tie them all into one neat framework. So, I would suggest you to start with [this excellent tutorial](http://ikpp.si/att/26/Ullman%20%20Structural%20equation%20modeling.pdf), after that - [this paper (theoretical parts)](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v48/i03/paper) to understand better SEM in general as well as two major approaches to SEM (CB-SEM and PLS-SEM) and then, perhaps, take a quick look at [this paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4055079) to get a sense (don't try to understand everything right away) how the **full SEM analysis** (EFA $\rightarrow$ CFA $\rightarrow$ PM/SEM) should be **performed** and **reported**. Then you can return to this question to post small clarifying questions or post them as separate questions. Hope this helps.

**Note.** Two important aspects: 1) your full SEM model (both measurement and structural models) should be **hypothesized** by you, based on theory or, if theory doesn't exist for that knowledge domain, literature review as well as your assumptions and arguments; 2) the **mapping** between 26 items and 4 **latent** factors is exactly that hypothesized *measurement model* I was talking about.

Comment: Also note that you don't have "26 items dataset and 4 factors dataset" - you have two models - measurement (26 to 4 mapping) ans structural (paths between those 4 latent factors) and **a single data set**.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the structural model you talked about is between my 4 IVs and 2 DVs. Right? (I do not really understand as you said "the structural (paths between those 4 latent factors) and a single data set".)  Another question is about confirmatory factor analysis. Does it require new data to run? Thanks Thanks Thanks....HUG HUG HUG

Comment: @AvaXU: In addition to hugs (or instead, to not make other people here uncomfortable), you could upvote the answer :-). You understood correctly what constitutes the structural model. Any data set is a separate from models subject. It is preferable to use different data for CFA (vs the EFA's one). Either use different data set, or, if you have a single data set only, you can randomly split it into two parts - one for EFA, another - for CFA/PM. See [this](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_we_do_exploratory_and_confirmatory_factor_analysis_in_the_same_data_set2) for the relevant discussion.

Comment: @AvaXU: (cont'd)  If you plan to perform your analysis in `R`, you might want to read [this JSS paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v48/i02/paper) on `lavaan` package, which can be used to perform both CFA and PM.

Comment: @Alekandr Blekh I will upvote your well explained answer once I get 15 reputation. :-)  Thanks again!

Comment: @AvaXU: Don't worry about that and you are welcome. I hope that understand the topic better.